# SplashScreen Animation lag between activities

Tags: android, splash-screen

I want to make a SplashScreen before the main activity starts. I've been carefully replicating [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-splash-screen-tutorial/) tutorial but there are still problems.

In my code I have an animation in `SplashActivity`. But my `MainActivity` has so many elements to initialize that the animation in SplashScreen Activity is lagging a lot.

Is there any possible way to manage this? I tried to use `runOnUIThread` in the `onCreate` method of `MainActivity`, but that made the problem even worse.

Answer (score 1):

actually with 4.4 OS Google is asking to do away with splash screens.
You are better off putting some dummy screen -> splash screen -> main activity. Here dummy screen with no have anything in it.
Provided you want splash screen with no action bar. If you add empty action bar to splash screen you can keep as it is
splash screen -> main activity.
Time lag is due to android takes time to start activity with no action bar at the start of the application.

Comment: So adding an emply action bar can reduce lag at the end of SplashScreenActivity?

Comment: yes if you add empty action bar that will reduce the time lag.